# How to compile C program file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.04, gcc, c

I can't compile a C file in Ubuntu 18.04.

In terminal I used this command: 
`$ gcc -o abc.o abc.c -lm`, but it says that gcc is not found.

This exact command can compile a C program in Ubuntu 16.04 (which I used 
earlier).

Can anyone help how to fix this? As far as I knew that gcc was the compiler by default in Ubuntu. But in 18.04 things seem different. What happened to 18.04? 
Thanks!

Comment: So does Bionic have gcc, have you checked?

Comment: I don't know. But How? @George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is an indications that the `gcc` package either isn't installed or isn't installed correctly.

These symptoms can happen after a fresh install before an update and upgrade.

The resolution is to complete the install with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install gcc
```

Unless you inadvertently removed it, it's installed automatically with Ubuntu 18.04 just as it was with 16.04.  So the first two commands above should correct the issue.

This issue happens with a number of packages that needs upgrades and updates after a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks!     It needed fresh install of gcc. $ sudo apt install gcc  worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment that is worked.  You can contribute back to the community by clicking the checkmark of the answer.  This will do a number of things.  It'll let people having similar issues easily find workable resolutions... it'll also reward both the person supplying the answer and the new user.

Comment: is in not better to just install build-essential?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte The package `build-essential` is installed by default, just as `gcc`.  In this case the problem was with the `gcc` command.